# Understand heap dump in JVM

Tags: java, mysql, eclipse, hibernate, out-of-memory

I got an out of memory problem in using Hibernate loading data to MySql(MariaDB) database, and the error message:

```
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
Dumping heap to /home/abigail/p4/projects/dump/java_pid28663.hprof ...
Heap dump file created [228930060 bytes in 0.584 secs]
22:47:08,484 WARN  [org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.listener.TxConnectionListener] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 69) IJ000305: Connection error occured: org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.listener.TxConnectionListener@44e591b5[state=NORMAL managed connection=org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.local.LocalManagedConnection@721498af connection handles=1 lastReturned=1458020814817 lastValidated=1458020814808 lastCheckedOut=1458020815292 trackByTx=false pool=org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.pool.strategy.OnePool@359650cf mcp=SemaphoreArrayListManagedConnectionPool@7d036b73[pool=BombwordDS] xaResource=LocalXAResourceImpl@11bd5305[connectionListener=44e591b5 connectionManager=473a607d warned=false currentXid=null productName=MySQL productVersion=10.1.8-MariaDB jndiName=java:/jboss/datasources/BombwordDS] txSync=null]: javax.resource.spi.ResourceAdapterInternalException: Unexpected error
    at org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.BaseWrapperManagedConnection.broadcastConnectionError(BaseWrapperManagedConnection.java:688)
    at org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.BaseWrapperManagedConnection.connectionError(BaseWrapperManagedConnection.java:654)
    at org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.WrappedConnection.checkException(WrappedConnection.java:1934)
    at org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.WrappedStatement.checkException(WrappedStatement.java:1437)
    at org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.WrappedStatement.executeUpdate(WrappedStatement.java:418)
    at org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.DatabaseExporter.export(DatabaseExporter.java:64)
    at org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport.importScript(SchemaExport.java:447)
    at org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport.execute(SchemaExport.java:379)
    at org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport.create(SchemaExport.java:305)
    at org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport.create(SchemaExport.java:294)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:517)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1859)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl$4.perform(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:857)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl$4.perform(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:850)
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.classloading.internal.ClassLoaderServiceImpl.withTccl(ClassLoaderServiceImpl.java:425)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:849)
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.hibernate4.TwoPhaseBootstrapImpl.build(TwoPhaseBootstrapImpl.java:44)
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.service.PersistenceUnitServiceImpl$1$1.run(PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.java:154)
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.service.PersistenceUnitServiceImpl$1$1.run(PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.java:117)
    at org.wildfly.security.manager.WildFlySecurityManager.doChecked(WildFlySecurityManager.java:665)
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.service.PersistenceUnitServiceImpl$1.run(PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.java:182)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
    at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:320)
Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    at java.nio.HeapByteBuffer.<init>(HeapByteBuffer.java:57)
    at java.nio.ByteBuffer.allocate(ByteBuffer.java:335)
```

I got a memory analysis report through Memory Analyzer in Eclipse and a snapshot is attached.

[image]

According to the report, the OutOfMemory occurs when the total memory usage is 171.9MB. However, I have 8GB memory, and I have this VM setting in Eclipse:

```
-ea -Xms256m -Xmx4G -XX:MaxPermSize=512M
```

I am running 64 bit CentOS. I don't understand why the OOM occurs when the memory usage is so little.

[image]

Edited: VM settings:

```
-ea -Xms256m -Xmx4G -XX:MaxPermSize=512M -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -XX:HeapDumpPath=/home/abigail/p4/projects/dump
```

I have been able to load the same file to database without any problem a few days ago. Since then, my application has had little change. I don't know why there is a memory issue suddenly.

Edited:

[image]

Comment: please share your full process argument list

Comment: Please see the edit.

Comment: My assumption is that your driver tries to allocate a huge buffer for the query result. Can you check what is the buffer capacity (just put a break point in java.nio.ByteBuffer#allocate)?

Comment: @MaximKirilov, I attached another histogram. Does this help? I can't find java.nio.ByteBuffer in my Eclipse.

Comment: try to attach java sources. The histogram shows only already allocated objects...

Comment: There is no query result. this occurs when Hibernate initially loads data to database through import.sql configured under src/main/resources in the web application.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/106317/discussion-between-user697911-and-maxim-kirilov).

Comment: Found that break point. Unfortunately, debugger doesn't show the capacity number. public static ByteBuffer allocate(int capacity), it only shows arg0 and its value is 8192.

Comment: VM settings you have listed is for Eclipse or the Application you are trying to run ?

Comment: For the application, in Windows->preferences->java->installed jres, where i set the JVM for the applicaiton.

Comment: In place of setting these option for JRE, once try to set for the program/project you are trying to run, i.e. right-click on project -> run as -> Configuration -> Arguments tab -> VM Arguments, then apply and run.